# Delete array element if index position is greater than a specific value

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to delete elements from an array if its index is greater than a certain value. I am looking to do something like this:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = a.delete_if {|x| x.index > 1 }
```

I took a look at `drop`, `delete_if`, etc. I tried completing this using `each_with_index` like this:

```
new_arr = []
a.each_with_index do |obj, index|
    if index > 1
        obj.delete
    end
    new_arry << obj
end
```

How can I delete an array element if it's array position is greater than a certain value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some other ways to return `a` sans elements at indices >= `index`, which is probably better expressed as "returning the first `index` elements". All below return `["a", "b"]`).

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
index = 2
```

*Non-destructive (i.e., `a` is not altered)*

```
a[0,index]
index.times.map { |i| a[i] }
```

*Destructive (`a` is modified or "mutated")*

```
a.object_id #=> 70109376954280 
a = a[0,index]
a.object_id #=> 70109377839640

a.object_id #=> 70109377699700 
a.replace(a.first(index))
a.object_id #=> 70109377699700
```

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`slice!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-slice-21) and give it a range. It is a destructive method as indicated by the `!`, so it will mutate your array.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.slice!(2..-1)
```

a = `[1, 2]`

Answer (score 3):

`Array#first` gives you the first n elements.

```
b = a.first(1)
# => ["a"]
```

If you want to do it in a destructive way, then this will do:

```
a.pop(a.length - 1)
a # => ["a"]
```

Comment: Lets say I had an array that was 20 elements long and wanted to delete index positions 9 and up? That's more specific to what I am trying to do

Comment: I'm sure @sawa meant `n` where he wrote `1`. (s: `n` needs backticks.)

Answer (score 2):

You can append [`with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index):

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
a.delete_if.with_index { |x, i| i > 1 }
a #=> ["a", "b"]
```

Another example:

```
a = ("a".."z").to_a
a.delete_if.with_index { |x, i| i.odd? }
#=> ["a", "c", "e", "g", "i", "k", "m", "o", "q", "s", "u", "w", "y"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Going by your question, *"How can I delete an array element if it's array position is greater than a certain value?"*.

I assume what you want is that the final array you have should contain only elements before the specified index.

You can just do this:

```
your_array.select { |element| your_array.index(element) < max_index }
```

E.g

```
figures = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
figures.select{ |fig| figures.index(fig) < 3 }
# => [1, 2, 3]
```